# Problemas de conexión a recurso de red aplicacion web

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenos días, tengo una aplicación web que necesito que acceda a un disco donde debo leer y escribir archivos y este se encuentra en otra red, desde windows server me puedo conectar a esta unidad de red por medio de un usuario. Ahora el problema es el siguiente: para conectarme desde la aplicación web lo hago por medio de la clase [`NetworkConnection`](https://gist.github.com/AlanBarber/92db36339a129b94b7dd)

Pero cuando necesito copiar unos archivos de la unidad de red a una unidad propia del servidor (utilizo para almacenar archivos temporales) funciona en ocasiones, y en otras no (la mayoría falla). El mensaje que capturo como  "error" es el siguiente:

> Error connecting to remote share result=1219

El código puntual donde falla es este:

```
string usuario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usrConsultaNAS"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passConsultaNAS"];

NetworkCredential NCredentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, password);

using (new NetworkConnection(rutaCarpetasNAS, NCredentials))
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(OutFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document())
        {
            using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream))
            {
                doc.Open();

                PdfReader reader = null;
                PdfImportedPage page = null;

                foreach (var file in InFiles)
                {
                    reader = new PdfReader(file);
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                        pdf.AddPage(page);
                    }
                    pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Les Agradezco de ante mano sus consejos y ayuda.

Comment: Hola jeissoni22, el error parece estar relacionado con esta variable `rutaCarpetasNAS`, ¿podrías mostrarnos el contenido de esa variable?

Comment: hola @Flxtr  rutaCarpetasNAS = \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\usuario_recurso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx) dice esto acerca de ese error:

> **ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT**
>
> 1219 (0x4C3)
>
> No se permiten varias conexiones a un servidor o recurso compartido por el mismo usuario, utilizando más de un nombre de usuario. Desconecte todas las conexiones anteriores al servidor o recurso compartido e inténtelo de nuevo.

Lo cual se refiere a que has superado el número de conexiones permitidas por uno o más usuarios, en este caso yo utilizaría un nombre de usuario diferente y/o en su caso, aumentar el número de conexiones simultáneas a ese recurso compartido.

Realmente parece que tu código no tiene ningún problema, el tema es con el consumo de los recursos compartidos.